# Script that defines the best capital allocation based on backtest results gives unexpected results

Tags: python, statistics, trading, cryptocurrency

I created a trading software in Python, and I'm backtesting it from December 2022 until now.
I created some stats about that:

| Total number of Signals | SL | TP1 | TP2 | TP3 | TP4 | TP5 | TP6 | TP7 | TP8 | TP9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 617 | 48 | 27 | 33 | 25 | 26 | 160 | 121 | 37 | 65 | 75 |

Let me explain how to read this data, for example TP4 mean that 26 trades reach TP4 then they went in SL (Stop-Loss).
If the trade reach TP4, mean that it passed TP1,2,3.

I then calculate the probability for each SL and TP:

| Probability | SL | TP1 | TP2 | TP3 | TP4 | TP5 | TP6 | TP7 | TP8 | TP9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 7.78% | 4.38% | 5.35% | 4.05% | 4.21% | 25.93% | 19.61% | 6.00% | 10.53% | 12.16% |

This is sorted by probability:

| Sort Probability | SL | TP5 | TP6 | TP9 | TP8 | TP7 | TP2 | TP4 | TP1 | TP3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 7.78% | 25.93% | 19.61% | 12.16% | 10.53% | 6.00% | 5.35% | 4.21% | 4.38% | 4.05% |

Since signals work with leverage in crypto and we use leverage 20 type crossed.

Those are the distance for each TP and SL:

| Our settings with x20 leverage | SL | TP1 | TP2 | TP3 | TP4 | TP5 | TP6 | TP7 | TP8 | TP9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Without Leverage | -10.00% | 1.00% | 2.00% | 3.00% | 4.00% | 5.00% | 15.00% | 25.00% | 35.00% | 50.00% |
| With Leverage | -200.00% | 20.00% | 40.00% | 60.00% | 80.00% | 100.00% | 300.00% | 500.00% | 700.00% | 1000.00% |

Now the software that I create allows me to open a trade using max 8 TP.
I have the possibility to enable/disable Trailing Stop-Loss feature.

I would like to write a Python code to find the best strategy allocation for each 8 TP and find the worst tp to use and avoid it.
The idea is to find the right strategy to maximize profit and minimize loss based on my stats.

I tried using linear expression, but this is something new and I'm not sure it is the best way to do that and it looks I got wrong results.

Here my code:

```
import cvxpy as cp

# I tuoi dati
returns = [2, 3, 4, 5, 15, 25, 35, 50]  # I rendimenti di ogni TP
p = [0.0535, 0.0405, 0.0421, 0.2593, 0.1961, 0.0600, 0.1053, 0.1216]  # Le probabilità di ogni TP

# Le variabili di decisione
x = cp.Variable(len(returns))

# Il rendimento atteso
objective = cp.Maximize(cp.sum(cp.multiply(cp.multiply(p, x), returns)))

# Le vincoli
constraints = [cp.sum(x) == 1,  # la somma dei capitali allocati deve essere 1
               x >= 0,  # le frazioni di capitale non possono essere negative
               x <= 1]  # le frazioni di capitale non possono essere maggiori di 1

# Risolve il problema
problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
problem.solve()

# Stampa la soluzione
print('La soluzione ottimale è', x.value)
```